# Update a core data database on selecting a particular row in iOS9 swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ios9

I have 2 VC in my core data project. In VC1 I have a table view for displaying the names in my coredata database. And in my VC2 I enter the details for the entity. Now I want to update my database when user selects a particular row. When user selects a row it would move to the VC2 and display the name in the textfield and if the user updates anything in it,it would update.  I have my code below. Please suggest what I should do next.

Entering the details-

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class EnterDetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nametextfield: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    @IBAction func savedata(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        let appdelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let managedcontext = appdelegate.managedObjectContext

        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: managedcontext)

        let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedcontext)
        person.setValue(self.nametextfield.text, forKey: "name")

        do
        {
            try managedcontext.save()
            print("SAVED")

        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            print("could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

    }




}
```

VC1- Displaying in table view

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

    var people = [NSManagedObject]()

    let manai = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    //var person :NSMutableArray = []


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableview.delegate = self
        tableview.dataSource = self


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
           print("CALLING FETCHDATA")
        self.fetchData()
        print("RELOADING DATA")

        self.tableview.reloadData()
           }

func fetchData()
{
    let appdelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appdelegate.managedObjectContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")

    do
    {
        people = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]
        print(people)
        print("FETCHING DATA")

    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {
        print("could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return people.count

    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = self.tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellreuse", forIndexPath: indexPath) 


    let  person = people[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = person.valueForKey("name") as? String


        return cell

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        let appdelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let managedContext = appdelegate.managedObjectContext

       if editingStyle == .Delete
       {
        managedContext.deleteObject(people[indexPath.row])
        }
      do
        {
            try managedContext.save()
            print("SAVED")

        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            print("could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }


        }


        fetchData()

        self.tableview .reloadData()
        print("reload after delete")


    }


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == "segueupdate"
        {



        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's your problem but this looks very strange to me: `var managedobjectt = NSManagedObject()`.  What if you change to `var managedobjectt: NSManagedObject?` ?

Answer (score 0):

The designated initializer of `NSManagedObject` is
`initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`. You can't call the generic initializer `NSManagedObject()`.

In your case you could declare `managedobjectt` as (implicit unwrapped) optional

```
var managedobjectt = NSManagedObject!
```

To make sure that accessing the variable doesn't happen too soon in VC2 you could also move the code in `viewDidLoad()` to `viewWillAppear()`

Comment: okay i would provide my whole code and update my question just have a look.

Comment: So what is the declaring when I write as var managedobjectt = NSManagedObject()  and var managedobjectt = NSManagedObject! . Swift says you can declare a variable of particular type by giving () after the particular class. So what is the trouble here. Please explain a bit so that i can be a more clear.

Comment: Some classes provide a designated initializer. These classes must implement that initializer and must not use the generic one with the parentheses. `NSManagedObject` is one of them. In your case it's a placeholder anyway because it's going to be overwritten before being used.

Comment: If that is the case,  in which place we have to declare a generic type and in which place can we declare a designated initializer type ?

Comment: It's not a question of declaring the type, it's a question of it's initialization. You could always try to use the generic initializer. The compiler will tell you if it's not possible.